# Javascript: How to get object from object in an array

Tags: javascript

Sample data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": {
        "full": "JOHN",
        "rank": "SENIOR"
      },
      "mobile": "12345"
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "full": "HENRY",
        "rank": "SENIOR"
      },
      "mobile": "67890"
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "full": "SAM",
        "rank": "JUNIOR"
      },
      "mobile": "54321"
    }
  ]
}
```

i'm trying to get the total number of senior members from the data sample above, and i can get the **data.name** and **data.mobile**, but i can't get the '**rank**' data from the parent 'name' object. can anyone please guide me to obtain the rank data. below is my javascript:

```
function countRank(rank) {
    var i;
    for (i in rank.data) {
        if (rank.data[i] == "SENIOR") {
            i++;
        }
        document.getElementById('senior').innerHTML = 'Total senior members: ' + i;
    }
}
<div id="senior"></div>
```

Comment: You're using `i` for two different things at the same time.

Comment: @Musa is right. I think you should set the name «key» for first variable, and use another variable for count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this

```
var rank = {
    "data": [{
        "name": {
            "full": "JOHN",
            "rank": "SENIOR"
        },
        "mobile": "12345"
    }, {
        "name": {
            "full": "HENRY",
            "rank": "SENIOR"
        },
        "mobile": "67890"
    }, {
        "name": {
            "full": "SAM",
            "rank": "JUNIOR"
        },
        "mobile": "54321"
    }]
};

function countRank(rank) {
    var i = 0,
        arr = rank.data;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (var prop in arr[j]) {
            if (arr[j][prop].rank == "SENIOR") {
                i++;
            }
            document.getElementById('senior').innerHTML = 'Total senior members: ' + i;
        }
    }
}

countRank(rank);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RMfLe/1/)

```
 function countRank(rank) {
    var k=0;
    for (var i=0; i< rank.data.length; i++) {
        if (rank.data[i].name.rank == "SENIOR") {
            k++;
        }
        document.getElementById('senior').innerHTML = 'Total senior members: ' + k;
    }
}
countRank(rank);
```

Comment: -1. If we're using it in a for in, we can't possible increment it. Of course, bad practice using it on an array to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.data[0].name.rank
>>> "SENIOR"
```

Assuming that whole object is called `obj`:

```
var i=0;
for (i=0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj.data[i].name.rank);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function countRank(rank) {
    var count = 0;
    var arr = rank.data;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var name = arr[i].name;
        if (name.rank == "SENIOR") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    alert(count);
}
```

I checked it and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can find rank from above data easily.
checkout sample on jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uBnfu/

```
$.each(jsonData.data, function (index, value) {
                    alert(value.name['rank']);
                });
```